# recommendation on some papers/books about frontal solver used in FEM

Tags: finite-element, linear-algebra, numerics, linear-solver

I'm reading a program about computational plasticity, this program use frontal solver to solve the program, but I'm not familiar with frontal solver even after reading some papaers, so could you please recommend some papers about frontal solver that has:
(1)detailed algorithm about the storage of non-symmetric stiffness matrix
(2)detailed algorithm about the solving of such sparse matrix by using frontal method
(3)detailed algorithm about dealing with dirichlet boundary condition
so could you please recommend some papaers or books about this, thank you

Comment: Where have you already looked? "Frontal solvers" are one possible algorithm for writing direct solvers for sparse matrices. There is a nice summary on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontal_solver) for which I will add the disclaimer that I just heavily edited it to remove some historical bias and improve language.